# As well as about

Tags: grammar

Should the word **about** be repeated after as well as?

Last month I started attending the science workshop. As a result, I would like to write some articles about nature as well as **about** the science experiments we do in the school laboratory.

Comment: It's *entirely* a stylistic choice how much of the preceding element you repeat after ***as well as***. If you wanted, you could write *I would like to write some articles about nature as well as **write some articles about** the science experiments we do in the school laboratory.*

Comment: Or even *I would like to write some articles about nature as well as **I would like to write some articles about** the science experiments we do in the school laboratory.* I doubt anyone would ever *actually* write/say that, but I think it's syntactically valid.